# Submission of a traditional Windows desktop app to Windows Store

Tags: c++, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store

My company is considering submitting a traditional desktop application to Windows Store, targeting new Windows 10 OS.

It's a native Windows build, an archiver app that uses 7z.dll (SevenZip library).

It's a typical GUI application written in C++, and the installation setup is created using Inno Setup.

The main question is whether it's suitable for the Windows Store. And it involves the following sub-questions:

- Does the store accept traditional Windows apps, not specifically designed for the Store format or compatibility with Windows RT? Can it use traditional Windows API?
- Does it allow applications that use native DLLs (7z.dll in our case)?
- Does it require specifically crafted installation package in order to be admitted to the Store?
- Can a Windows Store desktop application freely access the file system to be able to create new archives and decompress existing archives, or it runs in some kind of sandboxed environment?

We've already tried Windows App Certification Kit, but it doesn't give the complete picture.

I plan to set up and award a bounty on this SO question.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft is just now adding desktop apps to the Windows store (August 2015).

Yes you are able to use Windows RT and Windows API.

Yes you can use native DLLs.

It requires a package to be admitted to the store. Hard to tell what you mean by specifically crafted as all apps are specifically crafted.

Yes the application will run just as if it was off a disk. Will be able to freely access.

The only things that run in sandboxed environments are universal apps and phone apps.

Although this link is from Windows 8.1, much of the information is still the same.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/08/listing-your-desktop-app-in-the-store.aspx

-

Comment: The "Centennial" feature (desktop apps in the Store) was announced at //build but is not yet available.

Comment: @Seth Kitchen: "Hard to tell what you mean by specifically crafted as all apps are specifically crafted.": I think the OP means to ask whether the app must be uploaded in a special format that is suitable for the app store. E.g., can an msi installer be uploaded as it is?